# Cannot Find name "LocationAccuracy"

Tags: ionic-framework

i got this error in ionic . all required method are updated/installed my computer . Line 47 checked so ive found location accuracy defined as private i guess this maybe the problem !

so this is error i got :

```
[13:56:00] typescript: e:/testpc/src/pages/address/address.ts, line: 47
Cannot find name ‘LocationAccuracy’.
```

and this is adress.ts file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { NavController, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

// Custom
import { CoreValidator } from '../../validator/core';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { StorageMulti } from '../../service/storage-multi.service';
import { Core } from '../../service/core.service';
import { Config } from '../../service/config.service';
import { TranslateService } from '../../module/ng2-translate';
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';
import { LocationAccuracy } from '@ionic-native/location-accuracy';

// Page
import { LoginPage } from '../login/login';
import { CheckoutPage } from '../checkout/checkout';

declare var wordpress_url;

@Component({
    selector: 'page-address',
    templateUrl: 'address.html',
    providers: [Core, StorageMulti, Geolocation, LocationAccuracy]
})
export class AddressPage {
    LoginPage = LoginPage;
    CheckoutPage = CheckoutPage;
    formAddress: FormGroup;
    login: Object = {}; data: Object = {}; rawData: Object;
    isCache: boolean; useBilling: boolean;
    statesBilling: any; statesShipping: any;
    countries: Object[] = []; states: Object = {};
    trans: Object;

    constructor(
        private http: Http,
        private storage: Storage,
        private storageMul: StorageMulti,
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
        private core: Core,
        private navCtrl: NavController,
        config: Config,
        translate: TranslateService,
        private Geolocation: Geolocation,
        private LocationAccuracy: LocationAccuracy,
        private platform: Platform
    ) {
        translate.get('states').subscribe(trans => {
            if (trans == 'states') trans = {};
            if (config['countries']) this.countries = config['countries'];
            this.states = Object.assign(trans, config['states']);
        });
        translate.get('address.location').subscribe(trans => this.trans = trans);
        this.formAddress = this.formBuilder.group({
            billing_first_name: ['', Validators.required],
            billing_last_name: ['', Validators.required],
            billing_company: [''],
            billing_address_1: ['', Validators.required],
            billing_address_2: [''],
            billing_city: ['', Validators.required],
            billing_country: ['', Validators.required],
            billing_state: [''],
            billing_postcode: ['', Validators.required],
            billing_phone: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, CoreValidator.isPhone])],
            user_email: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, CoreValidator.isEmail])],
            shipping_first_name: ['', Validators.required],
            shipping_last_name: ['', Validators.required],
            shipping_company: [''],
            shipping_address_1: ['', Validators.required],
            shipping_address_2: [''],
            shipping_city: ['', Validators.required],
            shipping_country: ['', Validators.required],
            shipping_state: [''],
            shipping_postcode: ['', Validators.required]
        });
        this.getData();
    }
    ionViewDidEnter() {
        if (this.isCache) this.getData();
        else this.isCache = true;
    }
    getData() {
        this.storageMul.get(['login', 'useBilling', 'user']).then(val => {
            if (val['login']) this.login = val['login'];
            if (val['useBilling'] == false) this.useBilling = false;
            else this.useBilling = true;
            if (val['user']) {
                this.data = val['user'];
                this.changeCountryBilling(this.data['billing_country']);
                this.changeCountryShipping(this.data['shipping_country']);
            }
            this.reset();
        });
    }
    reset() {
        this.formAddress.patchValue({
            billing_first_name: this.data["billing_first_name"],
            billing_last_name: this.data["billing_last_name"],
            billing_company: this.data["billing_company"],
            billing_address_1: this.data["billing_address_1"],
            billing_address_2: this.data["billing_address_2"],
            billing_city: this.data["billing_city"],
            billing_country: this.data["billing_country"],
            billing_state: this.data["billing_state"],
            billing_postcode: this.data["billing_postcode"],
            billing_phone: this.data["billing_phone"],
            user_email: this.data["user_email"],
            shipping_first_name: this.data["shipping_first_name"],
            shipping_last_name: this.data["shipping_last_name"],
            shipping_company: this.data["shipping_company"],
            shipping_address_1: this.data["shipping_address_1"],
            shipping_address_2: this.data["shipping_address_2"],
            shipping_city: this.data["shipping_city"],
            shipping_country: this.data["shipping_country"],
            shipping_state: this.data["shipping_state"],
            shipping_postcode: this.data["shipping_postcode"]
        });
        this.rawData = Object.assign({}, this.formAddress.value);
        this.updateShipping();
    }
    updateShipping() {
        if (this.useBilling) {
            this.formAddress.patchValue({
                shipping_first_name: this.formAddress.value["billing_first_name"],
                shipping_last_name: this.formAddress.value["billing_last_name"],
                shipping_company: this.formAddress.value["billing_company"],
                shipping_address_1: this.formAddress.value["billing_address_1"],
                shipping_address_2: this.formAddress.value["billing_address_2"],
                shipping_city: this.formAddress.value["billing_city"],
                shipping_country: this.formAddress.value["billing_country"],
                shipping_state: this.formAddress.value["billing_state"],
                shipping_postcode: this.formAddress.value["billing_postcode"]
            });
        } else {
            this.formAddress.patchValue({
                shipping_first_name: this.data["shipping_first_name"],
                shipping_last_name: this.data["shipping_last_name"],
                shipping_company: this.data["shipping_company"],
                shipping_address_1: this.data["shipping_address_1"],
                shipping_address_2: this.data["shipping_address_2"],
                shipping_city: this.data["shipping_city"],
                shipping_country: this.data["shipping_country"],
                shipping_state: this.data["shipping_state"],
                shipping_postcode: this.data["shipping_postcode"]
            });
            this.changeCountryShipping(this.formAddress.value["shipping_country"]);
        }
    }
    checkUseBilling() {
        if (this.useBilling) this.updateShipping();
    }
    changeCountryBilling(e) {
        if (this.states[e]) {
            this.statesBilling = this.states[e];
            this.formAddress.setControl('billing_state', new FormControl('', Validators.required));
        } else {
            this.statesBilling = null;
            this.formAddress.setControl('billing_state', new FormControl(''));
        }
        if (this.useBilling) this.formAddress.patchValue({
            shipping_country: this.formAddress.value["billing_country"]
        });
    }
    changeCountryShipping(e) {
        if (this.states[e]) {
            this.statesShipping = this.states[e];
            this.formAddress.setControl('shipping_state', new FormControl('', Validators.required));
        } else {
            this.statesShipping = null;
            this.formAddress.setControl('shipping_state', new FormControl(''));
        }
    }
    changeBillingState() {
        if (this.useBilling) this.formAddress.patchValue({
            shipping_state: this.formAddress.value["billing_state"]
        });
    }
    confirm() {
        this.storage.set('useBilling', this.useBilling);
        if (this.useBilling) this.updateShipping();
        if (JSON.stringify(this.rawData) != JSON.stringify(this.formAddress.value)) {
            if (this.login["token"]) {
                let params = this.core.objectToURLParams(this.formAddress.value);
                let headers = new Headers();
                headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
                headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.login["token"]);
                this.core.showLoading();
                this.http.post(wordpress_url + '/wp-json/wooconnector/user/update_profile', params, {
                    headers: headers,
                    withCredentials: true
                }).subscribe(res => {
                    this.data = res.json();
                    this.storage.set('user', this.data).then(() => {
                        this.gotoCheckout();
                    });
                    this.core.hideLoading();
                });
            } else {
                this.data = this.formAddress.value;
                this.storage.set('user', this.data).then(() => {
                    this.gotoCheckout();
                });
            }
        } else this.gotoCheckout();
    }
    gotoCheckout() {
        if (this.navCtrl.getPrevious() && this.navCtrl.getPrevious().component == this.CheckoutPage)
            this.navCtrl.pop();
        else {
            this.navCtrl.push(this.CheckoutPage).then(() => {
                this.navCtrl.remove(this.navCtrl.getActive().index - 1);
            });
        }
    }
    location() {
        if(!this.platform.is('cordova')) return;
        this.core.showLoading();
        this.LocationAccuracy.canRequest().then(can => {
            if (can) {
                this.LocationAccuracy.request(this.LocationAccuracy.REQUEST_PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY).then(() => {
                    this.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then(resp => {
                        let latlng;
                        if (resp['coords']) latlng = resp['coords']['latitude'] + ',' + resp['coords']['longitude'];
                        if (!latlng) return;
                        this.http.get('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=' + latlng).subscribe(res => {
                            if (res.json()['status'] == 'OK' && res.json()['results']) {
                                let address = res.json()['results'][0];
                                let city;
                                let country;
                                address['address_components'].forEach(component => {
                                    if (component['types'].indexOf('administrative_area_level_1') != -1)
                                        city = component['long_name'];
                                    if (component['types'].indexOf('country') != -1)
                                        country = component['short_name'];
                                });
                                this.formAddress.patchValue({
                                    billing_address_1: address['formatted_address'],
                                    billing_city: city,
                                    billing_country: country
                                });
                            }
                        });
                        this.core.hideLoading();
                    }).catch((error) => {
                        this.core.hideLoading();
                    });
                }, err => this.core.hideLoading());
            } else this.core.hideLoading();
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. I just uninstalled the npm module (which was installed in version 5.2.0) and reinstalled the correct version (for me 4.20.0) :

```
npm remove @ionic-native/location-accuracy
npm install --save @ionic-native/location-accuracy@4
```